# Creating an appointment calendar using JDBC/MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jdbc

So I'm practicing some stuff before my finals this week and I've come across a sample problem that has a particularly challenging conundrum. I'm supposed to display (in a JSP with MVC architecture) a table that has the 5 days of the workweek along the top of it as columns and then hour-long time-slots on the left hand side as rows and this table will be used for booking appointments into each cell of the table. I am using JDBC to access a MySQL database on my school server.

The SQL table I've created is holding the following information: The person's name who is reserving the appointment slot, the time of their appointment, and the day of the week that their appointment will be on. In previous projects, I had only dealt with 1 dimension (the header of each column) and it was easy to iterate through my list of objects and fill in the table that way. Now that there are seemingly 2 dimensions, I'm not sure what to do.

I thought about using a 2D array but I didn't think that would work because the rows would be Strings (for the days of the week) and the columns would be Objects of the Class I had made to store the peoples' appointment info. So I'm not sure if making a 2D array with different types is even possible. I THEN thought about maybe just storing the Day and Time information in the 2D array and iterating through that to make the table but then I'm not sure how I would get the person's name.

I am very lost and hoping that my final doesn't have this sort of challenge in it. I apologize about the long winded post. Any ideas?

[A picture of what the final product should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfqVZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 2D array like you said and then you would need to make sure to add the empty elements for the timeslots/day when there is nothing scheduled. I think it's not ideal use of memory.
I would use a `Map<String, Map<String, String>> appointment` where `appointment.get(day)` would give you null or a map for the alloted timeslots of that day, ie. `appointment.get(day).get(timeslot)` would give you null if the slot is empty or the name of a person. Or `${appointment[day][timeslot]}`